# How can I accurately track user interaction coordinates in JavaScript, accounting for page scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a web application where I need to monitor user interactions such as hover, click, and input. My current JavaScript code functions well when there's no need for page scrolling. However, on pages with extensive content like blog posts that require scrolling, the code doesn't capture the precise coordinates from the topmost position of the entire page. Instead, it currently captures coordinates relative to the visible viewpoint on the screen, which becomes problematic when scrolling is involved. How can I modify my code to accurately capture coordinates regardless of the page's scroll position?

```
let hoverTimer;
let previousState = '';
let isEventPending = false;
let delayedEventType;
const eventDelayConfig = 2000;

document.addEventListener('mouseover', function(event) {
    clearTimeout(hoverTimer);
    hoverTimer = setTimeout(function() {
        scheduleEvent(event, 'hover');
    }, 2000);
});

document.addEventListener('keyup', function(event) {
    setTimeout(() => {
        const currentState = event.key;
        if (currentState !== previousState) {
            scheduleEvent(event, 'input');
            previousState = currentState;
        }
    }, 2000);
});

document.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    scheduleEvent(event, 'click');
});

function scheduleEvent(event, eventType) {
    if (!isEventPending) {
        isEventPending = true;
        delayedEventType = eventType;
        setTimeout(function() {
            trackEvent(event, delayedEventType);
            isEventPending = false;
        }, eventDelayConfig);
    }
}

function trackEvent(event, eventType) {
    let currentPath = window.location.pathname;
    // Using sessions, I am fetching some data from backend
    if (session && session['web_pages'] && session['web_pages'].includes(currentPath)) {
        ajax.jsonRpc('/track/users', 'call', {
            'user_id': session.user_id[0],
            'event_type': eventType,
            'location_x': event.clientX,
            'location_y': event.clientY,
            'current_path': currentPath
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX